# Are De Broglie relations only applicable to particles that have zero potential energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

De Broglie relations are always written as:
$$E=h\nu$$
$$p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$$
However, it doesn't make sense when you have waves that are eigenstates of a Hamiltonian operator with a non-zero potential. That is because that would give us a direct relation between momentum and energy: $\frac{E}{p}=v_p$, where $v_p$ is the phase velocity. This doesn't seem to make sense to me. So, would these equations be the same with the electron of the hydrogen atom, for example?

Comment: Why does the relation between $E$ and $p$ seem like a problem to you?

Comment: Because then you would have that for a state (eg state of electron on hydrogen Atom) as son as you know energy you Will know momentum, while on the hydrogen case momentum is a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Broglie's proposition is a limited-validity rule assigning a travelling wave to a freely moving particle. If we have eigenstates of a Hamiltonian with some potential term, we refer to Schroedinger's theory instead, which describes more complicated situations than de Broglie relations do.

The relation
$$
\nu = \frac{E}{h}
$$
is still valid in Schroedinger's description of Hamiltonian eigenstates, here $\nu$ is frequency of oscillation of function $\Psi$. This reminds of de Broglie's wave, but $\Psi$ of an Hamiltonian eigenstate is usually not a plane wave. It is usually some function concentrated in those regions of configuration space that are probable configurations of the system. For single electron atom, $\Psi$ is concentrated near the nucleus and it is not a travelling wave.

Hence, the relation
$$
\lambda = \frac{h}{p}
$$
is usually no longer applicable in this context, as there is no single momentum $p$ of the electron. Energy eigenstates have definite energy, but usually do not have definite momentum.

Comment: So could we say that they don't have definite wavelength as well? As long as every state can be expressed in term of infinite sum of momentum eigenstates we could say that every momentum eigenstate has its own wavelength and having infinite momentum eigenstate implies having infinite wavelength possibilities. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, when there is no single definite momentum, there is no single definite wavelength. Of course, one can possibly express any psi function as sum or integral of infinite number of functions $e^{i\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf x}$ but there is no single preferred wavevector or momentum there.